# Load product image everywhere in the Shopware 6 storefront from external URL at runtime without saving it in filesystem

Tags: shopware, storefront, shopware6

I am changing the image of a product from an external URL at runtime on saleschannel.product.load event. This all works fine, but when placing the order, it gives the error about

`` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sv3_dev`.`order_line_item`, CONSTRAINT `fk.order_line_item.cover_id` FOREIGN KEY (`cover_id`) REFERENCES `media` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) ``

I am guessing it is because I am overrwriting the media entity of the product with my custom implementation like this, so it does not find the media cover ID when inserting the order line item:

```
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($url);
        $media = new MediaEntity();
        $media->setId(Uuid::randomHex());
        $media->setUrl($url);
        $media->setMimeType(sprintf('image/%s', $pathInfo['extension']));
        $media->setFileExtension($pathInfo['extension']);
        $media->setFileName($pathInfo['filename']);

        $productMediaEntity = new ProductMediaEntity();
        $productMediaEntity->setId(Uuid::randomHex());
        $productMediaEntity->setMedia($media);

        $productMediaEntity->setPosition(0);
        $mediaCollection = new ProductMediaCollection([$productMediaEntity]);
        $entity->setMedia($mediaCollection);
        if ($entity->getCover() === null) {
            $entity->setCover($productMediaEntity);
        } else {
            $entity->getCover()->setMedia($productMediaEntity->getMedia());
        }
```

Is there a way to dynamically change the image at run time everywhere in the storefront?

I cannot save the image / media in the filesystem due to some copyright clause which does not allow the images to be downloaded in the shop. We can only load it at runtime.

Comment: instead of overwriting an existing media entity and the cover, you may want to simply add it additionally. in the storefront you make some template changes, so that only your external image is shown

Comment: @MichaelT I see. But then that would need to be done for all different templates wherever the product is shown, am I right? Or is there a single point of entry for it which will apply it everywhere?

Comment: yes, there is one template for listings, sliders and so on and of course the product detail page

Comment: @MichaelT is it not possible to load the image from a URL directly, instead of passing a media object in sw_thumbnails?

Comment: I can obviously add an img tag, but that is not what I am asking. I mean all the responsive functionality that sw_thumbnails provide, is it not possible to do that same with just a URL instead of a media object?

Comment: @MichaelT I am doing what you suggested, and it works using the event `sales_channel.product.loaded` but it does not work as intended after the order is placed. Till the confirm cart page, it still shows the image, but when the order is finished, it shows the default placeholder image http://i.imgur.com/CNWIhb0.png
I tried using the `order_line_item.loaded` as well and my code gets triggered before the finish page with expected media item, but after the finish page loads it does not have the cover media entity in the line item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who stumbles upon this, dynamically adding the media entity like mentioned in the question works for the rest of the shop except when placing the order, as it requires a media ID due to `FK` constraint. So what I did was that I created a `media` entity from the `mediaRepository` and used that ID as reference for the order instead of the `Uuid::randomHex()` without saving the actual image in the filesystem.